# Web App Bot - .NET Text to Speech not working

Tags: azure, botframework, cortana, azure-cognitive-services

Working with the Azure Web App Bot SDK v3.
I try to output text and speech at the same time.

```
        messageActivity.Text = information;
        messageActivity.Speak = information;
        messageActivity.Locale = "de-DE";

        await context.PostAsync(messageActivity);
```

Cortana nor Direct Line nor the Bot emulator does speak something out. However, the Bot does receive the text to speak out loud.

[image]

In addition, even

```
await context.SayAsync(information, information);
```

isn't working. I seems like there is an issue with the localization or something. I ran out of ideas.

Direct line is configured as following

```
  const speechOptions = {
    speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({ subscriptionKey: 'SUB_KEY_XXX', locale: 'de-DE' }),
    speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer({
      gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Male,
      subscriptionKey: 'SUB_KEY_AGAIN',
      voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (de-DE, Michael)'
    })
  };
```

Sidenote: Voice to text works flawlessly.

EDIT: Direct Line does work now. While I was using a iFrame for demonstration purposes, the voice output only works if the input also was provided via voice input. [However, you can change that behaviour as well](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1179).

Comment: I am not sure about Cortana or the emulator, but I know for the web chat with the Direct Line the bot only speaks when spoken to. So you might need to set the speak and also speak to the bot first.

Comment: Have you set the message's InputHint property?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-input-hints?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Comment: When using speech in the emulator, are you supplying a MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword (these are required for speech to function correctly in the emulator)?

Comment: @EricDahlvang yes I did provide the values. I am going to experiment with the InputHint. Will let you know the results.

Comment: Did update the post. Direct Line works now. Cortana and Emulator still won't output anything.

Comment: did u ever find a solution to this

Comment: @Sana no. I switched to english which works...

Answer (score 0):

You should try a well formed SSML wrapper if you want the informationText to speak in Cortana.

```
msg.speak = "<speak version=\"1.0\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis\" xml:lang=\"de-DE\"> <voice languages=\"de-DE\"  gender=\"male\"> Haben Sie Wien schon bei Nacht gesehen? </voice><voice languages=\"de-DE it\"  gender=\"female\"> Nein. </voice></speak>
```

Also note that Cortana only officially supports en-US for locale and market for third party skills.  Though you can do a lot of cool things with other voices and locales, there are a few quirks and you can run into issues.

Comment: Doesn't work either. Based on MSDN, SSML isn't required. Plain text should work as well.

Comment: For Cortana, if the speak message doesn't start with <speak its interpretted as plain text. The example posted works for me on desktop, mobile, and Invoke. However, on desktop, tts is done on the box so I needed to install the DE language pack.

Comment: how do you even call the web app bot without EN as primary language?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-localization?view=azure-bot-service-3.0 ''setPreferredLocale''

Comment: That is great, but I can't even call the bot without EN as primary language. (ask xxx yyyyyyy doesnt work) So I assume your OS system language is english and you switch the preferred locale on the bot side?

Comment: Botframework v4 can operate in any locale (so chatbots can support any locale). Cortana can operate in most locales -and supports first party skills in those locales.  Cortana THIRD PARTY skills ONLY support LU in US region and english.  (But the Cortana TTS can also be in any Bing supported locale). So... send a request to Microsoft to support third party skills in your region.